# How to run Tmux inside userdata?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops

I am trying to deploy a flask application at the launch of EC2 server through userdata using tmux. I am running below command to do so but it doesn't create a session but it works when I run the same command from putty. Please help.

```
/usr/bin/tmux new-session -d -s 0 "gunicorn Path_To_SDTM_Flask:application -b localhost:8000 --timeout 90000"
```

Note: There is no error in the CloudInit logs.

Comment: If this is just a dev/test machine then why start the app in userdata? If a production system, then this is definitely not the way to run a Python app.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's pre-installed in the used AMI ? 
Try define this is bash by adding before

```
#!/bin/bash
```